# Getting error in android app The constructor ArrayAdapter<R.string>(Menu, int, String[]) is undefined

Tags: android, android-listview

i am Getting error in android app The constructor ArrayAdapter(Menu, int, String[]) is undefined
this is my code:

```
package com.example.may_sec;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity

{
//the menu options:
String activitys1[] = {"MainActivity", "Splash"};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(Menu.this, 0, activitys1) );

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


}
```

i did some search hear but can find an answer..

Comment: Did my answer make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(Menu.this, 0, activitys1) );
```

to

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, 0, activitys1) );
```

capital "S" on "string"